# Yii - DB two column data display at once

Tags: php, yii

How to display the db data at once with different column?

This is my `YII` dropdown:

```
echo CHtml::dropDownList('select_gamecat',"",
     CHtml::listData(GamesType::model()->findAll(),
     'id', 'descr_en', 'descr'), //<--here
     array(
         'empty' =>  Yii::t('labels', 'choosecat'),
         'id' => "select_gamecat", 
         'class' => "inputs",
         'style'=>'width:369px'
      ));
```

I wish to combine the `'descr_en'` and `'descr'`

I tried `'desrc_en.desrc'` and `'desrc_en + desrc'` but both doesn't work.

Any Suggestion ? Thanks

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try it with an [anonymous function](http://php.net/manual/en/functions.anonymous.php):

```
echo CHtml::dropDownList('select_gamecat',"",
     CHtml::listData(GamesType::model()->findAll(),
            'id', function($data){
                return $data->descr_en.$data->descr; 
            }),
     array('empty' =>  Yii::t('labels', 'choosecat'),'id' => "select_gamecat", 'class' => "inputs",'style'=>'width:369px'));
```

**Explaination**

Yii will check if the third parameter is an anonymous function, if yes, it will run it (with [call_user_func](http://php.net/manual/en/function.call-user-func.php)) and the first parameter is the current model.

Comment: can u try mix my previous code for me ? cause when i mix your code ...many error

Comment: Like this, or do you need more? And can you please tell my what's not working?

Comment: same...im using Dreamweaver ... i pasted your code and giving me 3 red line

Comment: and the red lines? I need more information, I can't see what's not working.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/63689/discussion-between-the-smile-and-dinistro).

Answer (score 0):

you could recreate your array , as:

```
$models = GamesType::model()->findAll();
$data = array();

foreach ($models as $model)
    $data[$model->id] = $model->descr_en . ' '. $model->descr;     

echo CHtml::dropDownList($model, 'id', $data ,array('prompt' => 'Select'));
```

Comment: i think this is not a "Yii-like"-way

Answer (score 0):

Just you need to create a getter in model class `GamesType` as:

```
class GameTypes extends CActiveRecord {
    # ...
    public function getDesrc_enAndDesrc() {
        return "$this->desrc_en $this->desrc";
    }
    # ...
}
```

then use above getter as property in `CHtml::listData` method as:

```
echo CHtml::dropDownList('select_gamecat',"",
     CHtml::listData(GamesType::model()->findAll(),
     'id', 'Desrc_enAndDesrc'), # <== HERE
     array('empty' =>  Yii::t('labels', 'choosecat'),'id' => "select_gamecat", 'class' =>     "inputs",'style'=>'width:369px'));
```